# Mactex + Vimtex Live Preview is Delayed

Tags: vim, latex

I just setup Zathura to view PDFs.  I'm using vim as the text editor, with vimtex as a plugin.  I'm able to successfully view the PDFs, but the updates are delayed.

There seem to be two key difficulties: 
1) I have to click on the PDF so the update is reflected 2) the update takes a few seconds to be reflected after clicking on the PDF.

Is there any way to resolve either or both of these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Based on my personal experience, Mactex + Vimtex was quite slow when it comes to compile & preview processes. Until now, I still don't know why.

I am recently migrating to Visual Studio Code and used [Vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) & [LaTeX Workshop](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) extensions. It's working perfectly fine and fast. You should give it a try if you don't find any workaround on this later.

Comment: can you use custom snippets through this?

Answer (score 1):

I am using `vimtex` for latex preview too. I am on macOS 10.15, and using `skim` instead of `zathura` to view PDFs and I don't have such an issue. You can give it a try to figure out whether the issues occur in `zathura` or `vimtex`. And you can also use `:checkhealth` in neovim (similar but different cmd for vim) to check if `vimtex` is working normally.

My settings are listed below:

```
" skim can be installed with brew

" vimrc
Plug 'lervag/vimtex', {'for': ['tex']}

"vimtex
let g:tex_flavor='latex'
let g:vimtex_view_method='skim'
let g:vimtex_quickfix_mode=0
set conceallevel=1
let g:tex_conceal='abdmg'
```

Happy vimming